# projecting a boundary on a curved surface to boundary in xy plane

Tags: differential-geometry, analytic-geometry, surfaces

Say I have a bendable 2D sheet, on which I've drawn a circle. The sheet can bend, but it cannot be stretched or shrunk in any direction within its tangent plane. I then drape the sheet over a surface with coordinates $(x,y,z(x,y))$. I want to know the shape of the circle as projected on the $xy$ plane.

I'm assuming the surface has no overhangs.

I'm setting up the problem by saying the sheet has internal coordinates $(u,v)$, and a displacement field then maps those points to points on the surface: $(x(u,v),y(u,v),z(x,y))$. But I'm not sure how to enforce that there is no stretching/shrinking in any direction, since it's more than enforcing constant area.

Short of a final answer, does this type of 2D deformation have a name? Can you point me to any references? I'm not a differential geometry person, so the lower level, the better.

If the answer is not well defined in the presence of Gaussian curvature, let’s assume there is none.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is an example of an isometry: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isometry